# Dock windows form to the right of taskbar (and left of notification area / systems tray) in C++

Tags: c++, winforms

I am an intermediate in VC++ and trying to accomplish the following:-

1. Dock a timer created using Windows forms to the extreme right of the taskbar (and to the left of the notification area or system tray).
2. Make it responsive (match its height with that of the taskbar, even when the taskbar is resized and shift it left/right if notification area width increases/decreases i.e. number of icons in notification area changes).
3. If "show contacts on the taskbar" option in taskbar settings is turned on and/or any toolbars option is checked (ex - address, links, desktop or custom), it will appear to the left of my timer.
4. If the taskbar is docked left/right, rotate the timer and apply the above conditions.

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and CLR with VC++ (Winforms) to develop my application. Sorry for my bad english.

Example Screenshot of another application:-
[image]
Used inspect as advised by @Jimi sir:-
[image]

Comment: That looks like a [Desk Band](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl/nn-shobjidl-ideskband2). See also [Taskbar Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/taskbar-extensions) -- It also looks like you have already asked this question before (another account, but the same *graphic sample*).

Comment: See also [ITaskbarList interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-itaskbarlist) (and the interfaces that extend this one).

Comment: Yes @Jimi. I got no appropiate answers sir. That's the reason of my re-post. I am new to this forum too. Forgive me if I did something wrong. The screenshot I posted is not a deskband I guess because when I right click on the taskbar and goto toolbars, I only see the default options (i.e. Address, Links and Desktop) and not anything else.

Comment: It can't be removed by the user too. Right-click on the timer doesn't work either. Only on left click, another form appears displaying the summary.

Comment: See [ITrayDeskBand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl/nn-shobjidl-itraydeskband), [IBandSite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ibandsite). This article can help: [Shell Extensibility - Explorer Desk Band, Tray Notification Icon](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39189/Shell-Extensibility-Explorer-Desk-Band-Tray-Notifi). -- See what that Taskbar object actually is using Spy++ and [Inspect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects)

Comment: I used inspect and took the screenshot (attached it to my original post). Please help if you can figure out something from it. @Jimi